# How to extend ActionView::Template::Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

With Rails 6.0, the `to_spreadsheet` gem raises the following error:

```
Invalid formats: "xlsx", "html"
…/gems/actionview-6.0.0/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:288:in `formats='
```

This gem aside, it seems that [ActionViews `lookup_context.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb) now raises an `ArgumentError` when formats other then a few basic ones (`[:html, :text, :js, :css, :xml, :json]`) defined in [ActionViews Template `types.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/template/types.rb) are used.

I tried to extend the basic types like so:

```ruby
ActionView::Template::Types.symbols.concat([:xlsx, 'xlsx', 'html'])
```

Although this did indeed add to the `ActionView::Template::Types`, Rails still raises the `ArgumentError` described above.

So can these types actually be extended the way I did? Or am I on the completely wrong track to mitigate this error?

Note: MIME-Type for `.xlsx` is registered by the gem, thats why it worked with Rails versions < 6.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To register a new MIME type, you should add it to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`...which should have a commented example of how to add a MIME type (`# Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf`).

I would consider not using the `to_spreadsheet` gem. The last commit was 9 months ago. This may not mean it doesn't work...but I would be skeptical.

Comment: Correct MIME-Type is [registered by the gem already](https://github.com/glebm/to_spreadsheet/blob/master/lib/to_spreadsheet/rails/mime_types.rb), thats why it works with Rails < 6.0. You are right about questioning whether the gem is abandoned though.